# factory global variable undefined in polymer 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, factory, polymer-3.x

I try to import leaflet in Polymer 3 with Typescript. 
As soon as i try to import it with

`import * as L from 'leaflet';`

I get the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined
    at leaflet-src.js:6
    at leaflet-src.js:7`

The problem seems to be that in the factory, global is undefined

`(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) : typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) : factory(global.L = {});
})(this, function (exports) {`

[Error in Chrome Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5UEv.png)

As far as I understand it wants to bind L to the window. The problem with polymer 3 is that it does not work like that becouse there is no window or anything like that.

Is there any way I can import leaflet? Can I set the global variable in Polymer 3 or automatically let it bind to something else without changing the library?

Comment: do you have something in this varables if type "import varable from 'leaflet';"

Comment: @VadimHulevich sry Im not sure if I understand the question right, but the only thing I wrote was the import and `let map = new L.Map('map')` to test it. If your question is if I can use `import L from 'leaflet' `. I can not. Typrscript does not allow it.